# Set ComboBox Text on Basis of SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am trying to set the `Text` property of ComboBox on the basis of SelectedIndex but the problem is `Text` is becoming `String.Empty` after changing the Index of Combobox.

Each Item in ComboBox correspond to a string in `DataTable` having 2 columns `Name`, `Description`

What i need is when users select's a Name (Index Changes) when i want to show the Description of that in `ComboBox`

What i have tried :

```
private void tbTag_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the data for the selected index
    TagRecord tag = tbTag.SelectedItem as TagRecord;

    // after getting the data reset the index
    tbTag.SelectedIndex = -1;

    // after resetting the index, change the text
    tbTag.Text = tag.TagData;
}
```

How i have populated the Combobox

```
//load the tag list
DataTable tags = TagManager.Tags;

foreach (DataRow row in tags.Rows)
{
    TagRecord tag = new TagRecord((string)row["name"], (string)row["tag"]);
    tbTag.Items.Add(tag);
}
```

Helper Class Used :

```
private class TagRecord
{
    public TagRecord(string tagName, string tagData)
    {
        this.TagName = tagName;
        this.TagData = tagData;
    }

    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public string TagData { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TagName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
private void tbTag_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TagRecord tag = tbTag.SelectedItem as TagRecord;
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tbTag.Text = tag.TagData));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because -1 index in `ComboBox` means that no item was selected ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx)) and you are trying to change text of it. I would create one more element (at index 0) and make it change text depending on selection:

```
bool newTagCreated = false;

private void tbTag_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TagRecord tag = tbTag.SelectedItem as TagRecord;
    TagRecord newtag = null;

    if (!newTagCreated)
    {
      newtag = new TagRecord(tag.TagData, tag.TagName); //here we change what is going to be displayed

      tbTag.Items.Insert(0, newtag);
      newTagCreated = true;
    }
    else
    {
      newtag = tbTag.Items[0] as TagRecord;
      newtag.TagName = tag.TagData;
    }

    tbTag.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: each time a new item is inserted when user selects any of the index and for the newTag a reverse index is created

Comment: Yeah added check to see if newtag was already created and update it accordingly.

Comment: Also maybe there is a way of doing that using `Text` property of combobox ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx)) but not sure if it going to help.

Comment: thnx for trying! but i found a solution (Posted below).